# Allowing access to a PersistentVolumeClaim to non-root user

Tags: permissions, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

In kubernetes I can use a [PersistentVolumeClaim](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#persistentvolumeclaims) to create some storage, which I can later mount in some container.

However if the user in the container is not root, that user will not be able to access that directory because it is owned by root.

What is the right way to access such a volume? (I did not find any user/permission options both when creating and mounting that volume.)

Answer (score 12):

First, find out the UID number your process is running as.

Then you can tell Kubernetes to chown (sort of) the mount point of the volume for your pod by adding [`.spec.securityContext.fsGroup`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/workload-resources/pod-v1/#security-context):

```
spec:
  ...
  securityContext:
    fsGroup: 2000
```

> `fsGroup`: integer: A special supplemental group that applies to all containers in a pod. Some volume types allow the Kubelet to change the ownership of that volume to be owned by the pod: 1. The owning GID will be the FSGroup 2. The setgid bit is set (new files created in the volume will be owned by FSGroup) 3. The permission bits are OR'd with rw-rw---- If unset, the Kubelet will not modify the ownership and permissions of any volume.

Comment: We tried this with persistent volume claims but it didn't work out. Worked well for regular mounted volumes though.

Comment: That's weird. I am using it with PVCs.

Comment: I suspect its a GKE quirk... are you running on GCP? The fix for us to get around this on GKE was to use an init container. The suggestion is in this thread: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/2630

Comment: Yeah, tell me about it.  This is really ruining my day.

It seems that the confusion comes in with the fact that different volume types have differing levels of support. Unfortunately both HostPathVolumeSource and NFSVolumeSource contain the notice:
"...volumes do not support ownership management or SELinux relabeling."
https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.10/

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same issue in GKE environment. **securityContext** is not fixing permission issue. Here i what i have done.

1. Create a non-root user in Dockerfile and grant necessary permission to directories.

> ```
> RUN adduser -s /bin/sh -u 1100 --disabled-password foo
> RUN apk add sudo
> RUN mkdir /app
> RUN mkdir /app/logs 
> RUN chown -R foofoo /app /app/logs
> RUN chmod -R 777 /app/logs/
> USER foo
> WORKDIR /app
> ```

2. Mount the PVC into pod in the deployment yaml file
3. Create the same user in GKE worker node and grant the necessary permission to mount the path.

> /var/lib/docker/volumes/47aa3xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx19dc2c864ed99676b/_data