# SolrCloud Persistent Volume Permission Problems Using Kubernetes

Tags: docker, solr, kubernetes, solrcloud

> Per Taking Solr To Production
>   (https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/taking-solr-to-production.html),
>   "Running Solr as root is not recommended for security reasons, and the
>   **control script start command will refuse to do so.**

Provisioning of the persistent volume occurred.  However, when we claim and mount that into the folder structure for our Pod, the permissions setup for that mounted folder are only writable as root.  Therefore, the SolrCloud micro services cannot either store its configuration files nor core/collection data or backups to the persistent volume.

**How should we go about addressing this permissions issue in Kubernetes, since Solr enforces the inability to use root via the Solr command / start script?**

[Here is also an excerpt from the running pod after mounting, showing the permissions problem (root ownership for data folder):](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwrPE.png)

Here is also information about the Kubernetes server version:

```
C:\Users\xxxx>kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"8", GitVersion:"v1.8.0", GitCommi
t:"6e937839ac04a38cac63e6a7a306c5d035fe7b0a", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2
017-09-28T22:57:57Z", GoVersion:"go1.8.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"windows/amd6
4"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"6", GitVersion:"v1.6.8+coreos.0",
GitCommit:"fc34f797fe56c4ab78bdacc29f89a33ad8662f8c", GitTreeState:"clean", Bui
ldDate:"2017-08-05T00:01:34Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.6", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"lin
ux/amd64"}
```

Please see below yaml, docker file and start script.

yaml file:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: "solrclouddemo1"
  namespace: "com-xxx-cppseed-dev"
  labels:
    app: "solrclouddemo1"
    version: "1.0.0"
data:
  config-env: dev
  zookeeper-hosts: xxxx.com:2181
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: "solrclouddemo1"
  namespace: "com-xxx-cppseed-dev"
  labels:
    app: "solrclouddemo1"
    version: "1.0.0"
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: "solrclouddemo1"
      version: "1.0.0"
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: "solrclouddemo1"
        version: "1.0.0"
        build: "252"
        developer: "XXX"
      annotations:
        prometheus.io/scrape.ne: 'true'
        prometheus.io/port: '8000'      
    spec:
      serviceAccount: "default"
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: ENV
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              key: config-env
              name: "solrclouddemo1"
        - name: ZK_HOST
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              key: zookeeper-hosts
              name: "solrclouddemo1"
        - name: java_runtime_arguments
          value: ""
        image: "xxx.com:5100/com.xxx.cppseed/solrclouddemo1:1.0.0"
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: "solrclouddemo1"
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 8983
          protocol: TCP
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "600Mi"
            cpu: "250m"
          limits:
            memory: "1Gi"
            cpu: "500m"
      restartPolicy: Always
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: "solrclouddemo1"
  namespace: "com-xxx-cppseed-dev"
  labels:
    app: "solrclouddemo1"
    version: "1.0.0"
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8983
  selector:
    app: "solrclouddemo1"
    version: "1.0.0"
---
apiVersion: policy/v1beta1
kind: PodDisruptionBudget
metadata:
  name: "solrclouddemo1"
  namespace: "com-xxx-cppseed-dev"
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: "solrclouddemo1"
      version: "1.0.0"
  minAvailable: 1
---
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: "solrclouddemo1"
  namespace: "com-xxx-cppseed-dev"
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: "solrclouddemo1"
  serviceName: "solrclouddemo1"
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: "solrclouddemo1"
    spec:
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            - labelSelector:
                matchExpressions:
                  - key: "app"
                    operator: In
                    values:
                    - "solrclouddemo1"
              topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
      containers:
      - name: "solrclouddemo1"
        command:
        - "/bin/bash"
        - "-c"
        - "/opt/docker-solr/scripts/startService.sh"
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        image: "xxx.com:5100/com.xxx.cppseed/solrclouddemo1:1.0.0"
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "600Mi"
            cpu: "250m"
          limits:
            memory: "1Gi"
            cpu: "500m"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8983
          name: http
        *volumeMounts:
        - name: datadir
          mountPath: /opt/solr/server/data
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 8983
        fsGroup: 8983
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: datadir
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          app: cppseed-solr*
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM xxx.com:5100/com.xxx.public/solr:7.0.0

LABEL maintainer="xxx.com"

ENV SOLR_USER="solr" \
    SOLR_GROUP="solr"

# AAF Authentication
ADD aaf/config/ /opt/solr/server/etc/
ADD aaf/etc/ /opt/solr/server/etc/
ADD aaf/jars/  /opt/solr/server/lib/
ADD aaf/security/ /opt/solr/

# Entrypoint
ADD docker/startService.sh /opt/docker-solr/scripts/

# Monitoring
VOLUME /etc
#ADD monitoring/monitoring.jar /monitoring.jar
ADD /etc/ /etc/

# Permissions
USER root
RUN apt-get install sudo -y && \
    chown -R $SOLR_USER:$SOLR_GROUP /opt/solr && \
    chown -R $SOLR_USER:$SOLR_GROUP /opt/docker-solr/scripts/ && \
    chmod 777 /opt/docker-solr/scripts/startService.sh 

# && \ chmod 777 /monitoring.jar

WORKDIR /opt/solr


ENTRYPOINT ["startService.sh"]
```

startService.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# docker-entrypoint for docker-solr

# Fail immediately if anything has a non-zero result status
set -e

# Optionally echo commands before running them for debugging.
if [[ "$VERBOSE" = "yes" ]]; then
    set -x
fi

# execute command passed in as arguments.
# The Dockerfile has specified the PATH to include
# /opt/solr/bin (for Solr) and /opt/docker-solr/scripts (for our scripts
# like solr-foreground, solr-create, solr-precreate, solr-demo).
# Note: if you specify "solr", you'll typically want to add -f to run it in
# the foreground.
echo "Invoking solr-foreground"
# Allow the clients to pass in java_runtime_arguments to tune the solr runtime when invoking the pipeline
if [[ -z "${java_runtime_arguments}" ]]; then
    echo "No java_runtime_arguments received, so using default values"   
    exec solr-foreground -c -noprompt  $@ 
else
    echo "Received custom java_runtime_arguments.  User will be responsible for prefixing all values passed with -a to allow SolrCloud to accept them.  User is also responsible for establishing the -a -javaagent:/monitoring.jar=8000-/etc/config/prometheus_jmx_config.yaml-/etc/config/prometheus_application_config.yaml-/metrics  which is used for Prometheus monitoring"
    exec solr-foreground -c -noprompt $java_runtime_arguments $@
fi
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allowing access to a PersistentVolumeClaim to non-root user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46873796/allowing-access-to-a-persistentvolumeclaim-to-non-root-user/46907452#46907452)

Comment: You can also force the default solr startup script to allow you to run Solr as root with `-force`

Comment: Unfortunately, As per our company policy, we can't run application inside containers as root user.

Answer (score 1):

Workaround: Use initContainers

```
# Before Pod Starts this will change the ownership of the initContainers:
initContainers: 
      - name: volume-mount-hack  
        image: busybox 
        resources: 
          limits: 
            cpu: 500m 
            memory: 1Gi 
          requests: 
            cpu: 250m 
            memory: 600Mi 
        command: 
        - /bin/sh 
        - -c 
        - "chown -R solr:solr /opt/solr/server/data" 
        volumeMounts: 
        - name: datadir 
          mountPath: /opt/solr/server/data
```

Make sure to use same volumeMouth details in the container spec, along with runAsUser

```
containers:
      - name: "${APP_NAME}"
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        image: "${IMAGE_NAME}"
        env:
        - name: ENV
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              key: config-env
              name: "${APP_NAME}"
        - name: ZK_HOST
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              key: zookeeper-hosts
              name: "${APP_NAME}"
        - name: ZK_CLIENT_TIMEOUT
          value: "30000"
        - name: java_runtime_arguments
          value: "${JAVA_RUNTIME_ARGUMENTS}"
        command:
        - "/bin/bash"
        - "-c"
        - "/opt/docker-solr/scripts/startService.sh"
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "600Mi"
            cpu: "250m"
          limits:
            memory: "1Gi"
            cpu: "500m"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8983
          name: http
        volumeMounts:
        - name: datadir
          mountPath: /opt/solr/server/data
        securityContext: 
          runAsUser: 8983
```

Comment: This answer solved my issue but just needed to change `chown -R solr:solr` to `chown -R 8983:8983`